# AWS S3 access object witoout aws access key mention inthe https url

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-iam

I need to access object from Amazon AWS S3 without sharing access key in https URL.Can I generate URL without access key and successfully access the object on S3?

Currently I specify the access key as in the example below:

```
https://avnishrepotest.s3.amazonaws.com/abc.pdf?X-Amz-Algorithm=AWS4-HMAC-SHA256&X-Amz-Credential=<<**access_key**>>/20160119/us-west-2/s3/aws4_request&X-Amz-Date=20160119T111336Z&X-Amz-Expires=604800&X-Amz-SignedHeaders=host&X-Amz-Signature=0b6aa20a5949fd869d639f9c9968daa82d0e71c3416ae55d679aa054146b2689.
```

Can I generate url without AWS access key and successfully download the object?

Comment: Can you consider using a [presigned URL](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/ShareObjectPreSignedURL.html)?

Answer (score 2):

When you use a pre-signed URL in S3, you get a temporary credential set. It generates an access key and an hash where seat the hashed "private key". You can use this URL for  seconds.
Those credentials are temporary and not at all yours.
I don't understand why it can remains a problem to you.
What you want to achieve is not possible.
If you want to "hide" the access key, you can use an URL shortener but the information will remain accessible.

Comment: Actually I dont want to share the AWS access key with the client due to security purpose

Comment: Why is it a security lack to share a temporary access key?

Comment: this is 100% safe to share this signed url, access key is generated and temporary valid, and you don't share the secret key.

Comment: Suppose I have generate a pre signed url with expiration time 1 hour.So This url can be accessible for one hour from any client not specific client?

Comment: I am using below code to generate the presigned url-java.util.Date expiration = new java.util.Date();
   long milliSeconds = expiration.getTime();
   milliSeconds += 1000*60*60; // Request will expire after 1 hour.
   expiration.setTime(milliSeconds);
   GeneratePresignedUrlRequest generatePresignedUrlRequest = 
        new GeneratePresignedUrlRequest(bucketName, objectKey);
   generatePresignedUrlRequest.setMethod(HttpMethod.GET); 
   generatePresignedUrlRequest.setExpiration(expiration);

   URL url = s3client.generatePresignedUrl(generatePresignedUrlRequest);

Comment: Anyone having the pre-sign url can access the resource, but this has nothing to do with the access key been embedded. This is the definition of the pre-signed url. If you need to limit the access to other people, then use AWS IAM users or roles instead combined with S3 policies